# Node JS Request Response not working

Tags: node.js

This is my register route. If the registration is successful I want to redirect to the secret route. But the response is not working. When it is successful the page keeps loading and loading and doesn't redirect me to the secret route.

```
app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
   User.create({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
        email:    req.body.email
    }, function(err, result, res) { **HERE**
          if(err) throw err;
          res.redirect('/secret');
          console.log(result);
    });
});
```

I tried this and the /secret route works but when I do this it doesn't check for registration errors and immediately redirects to the secret route.

```
  app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
       User.create({
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password,
            email:    req.body.email
        }, function(err, result) { **HERE**
              if(err) throw err;
              console.log(result);
        });
        res.redirect('/secret');
    });
```

I tried to add return err. So if there is an error the function will exit.
But here the /secret route still is still shown when I intentionally made an error in the registration. So the return is not exiting the function.

```
app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    User.create({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
        email:    req.body.email
    }, function(err, result) {
        if(err) return err; **TRIED RETURN TO EXIT**
    });
    res.redirect('/secret');
});
```

Comment: any error ? you are getting

Comment: You need to pass this redirect inside of callback function I guess else it's gonna get called everytime even before saving data to the database

Comment: Yes its the res part that is the problem. Everything else is good

Comment: always use uniq name like `function(req, res)` its res will not repeat at anywhere

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

That it keeps loading and loading indicates that the create user function returns an error in the callback. Or an error occured in the callback.

In case of an error no reponse might be send which will result in a dangling request.

In your code the reason is that you have to remove the `res` from the create user callback otherwise you will hide the original `res` of the middelware callback, which will result in an error. But you also have to handle the case when create user itself results in an error.

Your callback could look that way:

```
function(err, result) { 
      if(err) {
          res.status(500).send('an error occured')
      } else {
         res.redirect('/secret');
         console.log(result)
      }
}
```

How exaclty the callback should look like depends on what you want to do in case of the error. You also might want to choose a different error code then `500` that would match better.

Comment: I just tried this and the page keeps on loading and loading after I hit the route. It didn't redirect me to the /secret. I guess I have to use res outside the User.create function.

Comment: @Pathway did you use the updated code? I write it on the mobile app, so the last update took some time to come through.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you're confusing the callback-based nature of asynchronous programming in normal NodeJS with regular sequential programming.

The call to `User.create` will return immediately, and lines following it execute prior to anything within the callback you provide. So your `res.redirect()` call will trigger the immediate response of a redirect to the client. When the callback finally runs, the request has finished.

Instead, you will want to perform the redirection inside of the callback function, after checking for potential errors.

Your code should end up looking like this:

```
app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    User.create({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
        email:    req.body.email
    }, function(err, result) {
        if(err) throw err;
        // Since we got here, things went well presumably
        res.redirect('/secret');
    });
});
```

Comment: I just tried this and the page keeps on loading and loading after I hit the route. It didn't redirect me to the /secret. I guess I have to use res outside the User.create function.

Comment: No, you don't. The reason that could happen is because the code will throw an exception if `err` is non-falsy. Check the console output of your application to make sure.

Comment: If you want it to send a response to the user in that case, you can use the code `t.niese` wrote above.